# How to Integrate AWS mediapackage in wordpress

Tags: wordpress, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-cloudfront, aws-media-convert

I am very new to aws services. In my website, I am thinking to show premium videos, but those should not be allowed to download by any paid user.

I will use AWS S3 as my hosting for all videos. but the problem is: these videos are not secured and anyone can able to download easily. BTW, I use wordpress, I got to understand how to integrate S3 with wordpress.

So, after searching more, I found this https://aws.amazon.com/mediapackage/  for secure video streaming (which is a combination of AWS s3 + mediapackage + cloudfront). Although, in theory, I could be able to understand, but I am not understanding how to embed S3 video securely in wordpress page using above AWS Services combination.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you want to deliver Video On Demand (VOD). This doc from AWS would be helpful in achieving that - https://docs.aws.amazon.com/mediapackage/latest/ug/gs-create-asset.html

For the security of your videos in S3 this article may be helpful -

https://help.optimizepress.com/article/656-setup-your-amazon-s3-bucket-permissions-to-protect-videos-you-use-in-the-video-player-element